# I want to dynamically change the color of the text view inside list view

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have this layout in which I have a listview. The content of list is defined in another layout.I have text views inside this layout and I want to dynamically change the color of the text view depending on some condition(like simple if else).Please let me know how to do this. 
Here is my code-:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.recentlist,
                new String[] { KEY_CAT, KEY_DATE, KEY_TID, KEY_AMO, KEY_DEB,KEY_CUR,KEY_BAL,KEY_FEES}, new int[] {
                R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4,R.id.textView5,R.id.textView7,R.id.textView6,R.id.textView8});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This particular layout I have added from another xml file to put the contents of listview in this.So I cant setTextColor by taking textView because it takes the id of this class's layout and not this layout.Please help me regarding this.

Comment: You have to create custom adptare and put color in getView()

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cant use a `SimpleAdapter` to perform this operation as SimpleAdapter only copies data from data set to TextView in your `ListView`. In order to handle color changes at run-time you should define a `CustomArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Override getView method of SimpleAdapter by extending it to your own class. Inside getView method, you can use View.findViewById and then do whatever you want to do with your TextView

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
// where vi is convertview
tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: Use Adapter to set text in listview and using converview you can set your text and text color.